# How can I ramp up the start of a motor?

Tags: motor, mains, home-automation, home-installation

I recently have had electrical roller shutter installed on my windows. They are wired (I put a home automation system behind, based on Shelly 2.5 [(wiring)](https://shelly.cloud/knowledge-base/devices/shelly-25/#wiring)). It works great, except that the motor, when solicited, starts very abruptly.

It is powered from 0 to 230V instantaneously and therefore starts with full power which is actually a bit frightening (I still jump when it starts, especially in the morning).

The motor is a [SOMFY LT 50 METEOR 20/17](https://www.somfypro.fr/trouver-un-produit/-/e-cat/1041532/LT_50_METEOR_20_17_x100_), its power is 160 W, current 0.75 A and the couple is 20 Nm.

Is there a way to ramp up the power supply?

[image]

Comment: You could use an NTC but most anything you add needs to go between motor and control, not at the outlet. How big is the motor? Terminology-wise you want a soft start, or ramp up. Smoothing out the power supply means something else.

Comment: _"I recently have had electrical roller shaders installed."_ - which ones? Do they have the same problem when operated with the supplied/recommended manual control?

Comment: @BruceAbbott: The automation part is in parallel to the supplied manual button (I should have made it more clear, this is why I initially mentioned the Shelly to show how it is wired). They work very well, it is just that they start too abruptly on a "human" level (electrically everything is fine, it is just that the motor starts full power and it makes me jump). EDIT: I added a better link to the wiring

Comment: @DKNguyen: I will have to check with the professional who installed them, but the couple will be between 15 and 20 Nm. Thanks for the terminology (I see how "smoothing" is the wrong word), I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: What will be needed depends on the type of motor in your roller unit. What brand and model is it?

Comment: Yes sorry @BruceAbbott, I should have had provided that in my question. I updated it with the link to the motor (in French unfortunately), and I copied the caracteristics